# Music software that can play multiple local music files simultaneously, and can be controlled with hot keys

Tags: audio, music, self-hosted, podcast, audio-player

I am looking for software that can play **locally stored** music files (e.g. ogg, wav, mp3 etc). I am searching for something that is able to play **two or more files at the same time**, e.g. a file of background ambience and a file with a song, over one another, with volume controls for each track.

The software also must be able to **loop** a track.

I would also love to be able to start and stop music files with **hotkeys** - e.g. pressing [a] makes foo.mp3 start to play, pressing [b] plays bar.wav, etc. This is not absolute crucial, but it would be really, really nice to have.

Those features are the main part. What comes next is basically an addition:

Furthermore, I would be interested in any kind of option that allows me to stream the music to a few friends. I am having a hard time coming up with results for this functionality, because everybody on the internet wants to have their streaming service (Spotify and similar) to their devices, however, I am looking for an option to set up my own stream of locally hosted music that can be received by somebody else over the internet. I am totally willing to jump through a few hoops, install or compile a self-hosted server of some kind, I just haven't found a solution for this yet.

For background: I intend to use this for audio layers for a pen&paper roleplaying campaign. I don't plan to do any podcasting or music streaming to a public audience, it is just a group of 4 friends.

Thank you, everyone!

Comment: Clementine Music Player is open-source and kinda similar to what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Most media players can run multiple instances with independent controls. For [VLC, for example](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Play_multiple_instances/), just remove the checkmark from *Allow only one instance*.

That said, you might need to "raise" the correct instance (bring focus to that instance) for keyboard shortcuts to take effect. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to select an instance, then apply the keyboard shortcut.

VLC also has a streaming feature, [enabling you to send to other network locations](https://www.howtogeek.com/118075/how-to-stream-videos-and-music-over-the-network-using-vlc/).